# How to display all products in a single page in opencart?

Tags: php, module, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

**I want to display all products in onepage while clicking a single button in main menu and also need to display category in main menu...**

thank in advance...!

Comment: You mean without any category and no pagination  ? ?  check [this](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=3889) if it helps you else will get back to you  soon,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. **Display Alll Product in one Page**
    You have to create separate page for displaying all products.

   1. Create Model file `catalog\model\catalog\allproduct.php` and paste
      code this http://pastebin.com/suF5TP3z
   2. Create Controller file `catalog\controller\productallproduct.php` and
      paste below code http://pastebin.com/jZq3hZyc
   3. Create View file
      `catalog\view\theme\default\template\productallproduct.tpl` and paste
      below code http://pastebin.com/1HNh3x73
      4 . Create Language file `catalog\language\en-gb\product\allproduct.php`
      and paste below code http://pastebin.com/EcyJH7F9

      5. Enable module from back-end You can see link in menu
         [image]
2. **Display All Category in Menu**

   1. Open and edit your category:
   2. Select tab Data:
   3. Find and Check:Top: Display in the top menu bar. 
      [image]

      **Note :** Only works for the top parent categories.You will need to check all the top level categories.It's Opencart bugs.

Comment: You're welcome @abdul.You can also sort,grid,list and display product by per page.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest don't make any change in the default theme codes and structure. If you already using a custom theme you can easily create a menu and define to all categories included all products under the one menu or button.
Lets get over with in that way : 
For example you have 5 categories. Every category includes over ten products or much.

- Create a brand (Manifacturer). This brand will be contain just 1 category. Give it a name like "All Products"
- Create a category and name it as "All Products".
- Create a menu which will display all products and define the menu display as category. Select the "All Products" category which is you just created.
- Go to product pages and click edit for each one. Click the "link" tab and the category textbox, choose "All Products" category. Make this simple edit for every product. I tried for you and it takes 4 / 5 seconds.
- Go to "Theme Setting" in your theme. Find "Display Products" or "Products in Category" setting. There are always pre-defined display limit in every theme and it goes next with pagination. Make a simple calculation like that ; how many product in your store, 50 ? 100 ?
- Setup the display limit bigger than your total product count.

That's it !

Maybe you would like to play menu css a bit. Like i said before, if you already using a custom theme, you dont need to fork your core codes especially the default theme.

Let me know if any help.

Answer (score 2):

The way i did its something like this

Controller : **ControllerProductCategory**

inside the index function replace

```
if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
    $limit = $this->request->get['limit'];
} else {
    $limit = $this->config->get('config_product_limit');
}
```

with

```
if (isset($this->request->get['viewall'])) {
            $limit = "";
} else if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $limit = $this->config->get('config_product_limit');
} else {
            $limit = $this->config->get('config_product_limit');
}
```

Also make this change to display all the products without category filter

replace this code

```
    if ($category_info) {
                $this->document->setTitle($category_info['meta_title']);
                $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
                $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);
```

With this code

```
if (($category_info) || ($category_id == 0)) {
    if ($category_id == 0) {
                $this->document->setTitle('all products');
                $this->document->setDescription('all products');
                $this->document->setKeywords('all products');
                $this->data['heading_title'] = 'all products';
                $category_info['description'] = '';
                $category_info['image'] = '';
      } else {
                $this->document->setTitle($category_info['name']);
                $this->document->setDescription($category_info['meta_description']);
                $this->document->setKeywords($category_info['meta_keyword']);
                $this->data['heading_title'] = $category_info['name'];
            }
```

and at the last create a new category , you can name it to anything you want. and give the link something like this

```
https://www.yourwebsite.com/yourCategoryname?viewall=viewall?viewall=viewall
```

You can place this link anywhere you want and it will load all the products without any pagination.

let me know if you still don't understand anything anyehere.

Comment: i need to display all products in single page without category and i want to all products button in  main menu and also to display all category in mainmenu...please help me how to do this???

Comment: buddy i am not at home.  will be help u out after tuesday . .